# Using unique objects for creating different rooms/namespaces in socket.io

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have a setup where an angularjs based frontend will subscribe to a socket.io based server for data updates, the subscription will be unique and will be based on an object, for example:

```
{
    "paramOne":"valOne",
    "paramTwo":"valTwo",
    "paramThree":"valThree",
    "paramFour":"valFour"
}
```

Now, multiple clients can subscribe to the same object structure and all these clients should be grouped together for which I am thinking of rooms/namespaces.

As per socket.io documentation, Rooms and namespaces are strings, now how can I acquire the room functionality but based on the above mentioned object.

Comment: Why not just add `paramRoomName` value to object? And then create room with `obj.paramRoomName`.

Comment: @OzgurGUL, But there is no predictable room name, The room is decided according to the combinations of the parameters. The clients which have same parameters and values should be in a same room, There can be many different rooms unique to the parameters.

Comment: I understand. So you can just turn that object to a string, get md5 of it.

Comment: I thought of it and tried it too, but if the order of the object properties is not guaranteed, it might not work, rooms might not match.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't say it. But you have to order keys and values in a way. (eg alphabetic)